# Cannot GET /api/signup - Using Postman and mongodb

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose, router

I am very new to mongoose and I made one signup api and while testing it using POSTMAN I'm getting these weird error as well when I refresh my http://localhost:8000/api/signup I get a message saying "Cannot GET /api/signup" and in my postman post request I am seeing an error message that says "Cannot POST /api/signup".

How would I get rid of these messages that are being displayed?

I am following a tutorial so I tried copying and pasting the code from the GitHub to make sure everything was perfect but I was still seeing these error messages.

My app.js file is:

```
    const express = require("express");
    const mongoose = require("mongoose");
    const morgan = require("morgan");
    const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
    const cookieParser = require("cookie-parser");
    require("dotenv").config();

    // import routes
    const userRoutes = require("./routes/user");

    // app
    const app = express();

    // db
    mongoose
        .connect(process.env.DATABASE, {
            useNewUrlParser: true,
            useCreateIndex: true
        })
        .then(() => console.log("DB Connected"));

    // middlewares
    app.use(morgan("dev"));
    app.use(bodyParser.json());
    app.use(cookieParser());

    // routes middleware
    app.use('api', userRoutes);

    const port = process.env.PORT || 8000;

    app.listen(port, () => {
        console.log(`Server is running on port ${port}`);
    });
```

my routes/users.js file is:

```
    const express = require("express");
    const router = express.Router();

    const { signup } = require("../controllers/user");

    router.post("/signup", signup);

    module.exports = router;
```

my controllers/users.js is:

```
    const User = require("../models/user");

    exports.signup = (req, res) => {
        console.log("req.body", req.body);
        const user = new User(req.body);
        user.save((err, user) => {
            if (err) {
                return res.status(400).json({
                    error
                });
            }
            res.json({
                user
            });
        });
    };
```

I am hoping to see a response in my browser that does not display an image that image that says Cannot GET api/signup and I am hoping that Postman is able to return data from my api

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It means there is no corresponding router setting to `/api/signup`

I think `router.post("/signup", signup);` should be `router.post("/api/signup", signup);`

This should work fine on PostMan.

But the browser url is a `get` request, so the request would still fail. You will need to send the `post` request by javascript then.

For example, something like :

```
fetch('/api/signup', {
  method: 'POST',
  body: 'signup data here'
})
.then(response => response.json());
```

Please let me know if the error still exist.

Answer (score 0):

There is a minor bug

`app.use('api', userRoutes);`

change to

`app.use('/api', userRoutes);`

Answer (score 0):

My issue was that when I installed mongoDB locally I had not properly installed it and was not using a /data/db folder. I was able to fully uninstall my older version of mongoDB and reinstall everything following this youtube tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MIByvzueqHQ